# ERROR: Error: Please install Android target: “android-22”

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I get the above error when running "ionic run android --device". Even though I have targeted "16" (corresponding to android 4.1.2) in

```
platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml --
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16" />
platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml --
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
platforms\platforms.json --
    {"android" : "4.0.0"}
```

Where else should I be looking for this setting? Is this something that comes predetermined with cordova / ionic versions? `ionic info` on my PC shows

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local:   Local version 3.8.11
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.5.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.2.2
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.10.36
```

Thanks a lot.

--EDIT (see karaokyo's answer)

Also fix property in `platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project must be set to build with API level 22. Change it to 16 or whatever version you have installed.

`Right click project > Properties > Android > Project Build Target`

Comment: I am using webstorm IDE, there is no "project" to click. Is there a file to check and edit? Found it in platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties.

Comment: Wait... so did you solve you problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: @Dinesh, using webstorm too i and it said that file was auto generated and should not be edited. I just copied from an older system with the target and pasted into /path-to-android-sdk/platforms/

Comment: @FemiOni Now in my case everything is managed from *top level* `config.xml` and the second-tier files (e.g. android manifest) are automatically updated by ionic/cordova build system.